# Hidden fields in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I access hidden fields in angular? I have an app, where I want to submit a form for each of items in the list. The form is simple - it has submit button and a hidden field holding the ID value. But it does not work. The value is empty.

I updated the default angular example to display the situation - the todo text is in hidden field.

http://jsfiddle.net/tomasfejfar/yFrze/

Comment: Could you make a simpler example of the problem? Here's a base fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andytjoslin/DkMyP/

Comment: Of course: http://jsfiddle.net/DkMyP/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your simpler fiddle, the problem can be fixed by using ng-init or setting an initial value in the controller. The `value` attribute won't effect the ng-model.

http://jsfiddle.net/andytjoslin/DkMyP/2/

Also, your initial example (http://jsfiddle.net/tomasfejfar/yFrze/) works for me in its current state on Chrome 15/Windows 7.

Comment: But that works only one time. Next time the variable is empty.

Comment: Ah, that's because in the todo example `todoText` is set to a blank string in the `addTodo` function.

Comment: obviously! oh, crap! :D Thanks! :D

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to hardcode anything in your javascript file, you can either load it via AJAX, or do:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="value" ng-init="model.value=1" value="1">
```

this way, you can keep the form functionality with JS off, and still use the hidden field in AngularJS

Comment: Use: `<input type="hidden" name="value" ng-model="model.value" ng-init="model.value =1 " value="{{model.value}}">`. This way changes to `model.value` will be updated in the input value.

Comment: there's no need to set a hidden value to the model value, since it's not something the user will change. the model value can be kept in the scope without altering the DOM

Comment: What if you want access to that model value (or some interpolated value) in a postback? It would be pretty handy then. I'm just highlight another useful use case for hidden fields.

Comment: then you wouldn't need a DOM node with a init hack, just a directive :)

Comment: ng-init="model.value=val" in combination with ng-if="val" does the trick for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to pass the ID from the ng-repeat to your code, you don't have to use a hidden field. Here's what I did:

For example, let's say I'm looping through a collection of movies, and when you click the "read more" link it will pass your ID to your JS code:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    {{movie.id}} {{movie.title}} <a href="#" ng-click="movieDetails(movie)">read more</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your JS code, you can get the ID like this:

```
$scope.movieDetails = function (movie) {
  var movieID = movie.id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.
It is a dirty trick, but it works (like most dirty tricks ;-)
You just use the form name as Your hidden field 
and always give the form the id "form"

```
<!doctype html><html ng-app><head>
<script src="angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function FormController($scope) {
  $scope.processForm = function() {alert("processForm() called.");
    $scope.formData.bar = "";
    try {$scope.formData.bar = document.getElementById("form").name;} 
    catch(e) {alert(e.message);}
    alert("foo="+$scope.formData.foo+ " bar="+$scope.formData.bar);
  };
}
</script></head><body>
<div ng-controller="FormController">
<form name="YourHiddenValueHere" id="form">
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.foo" />
<button ng-click="processForm()"> SUBMIT </button>
</form>
</div></body></html>
```

This allows You to use ONE Controller for ALL forms and send 
them to ONE server script.
The script than distinguishes by the 
form name (formData.foo) and knows what to do.
The hidden field names the operation in this scenario.

Voila - You have a complete application with as 
many forms You want and one server script 
and one FormController for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
<input type="hidden" name="livraisonID" value="{{livraison.id}}"/>
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

I have to correct (improve) myself: 
You can do it more elegantly:

```
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.foo" />
<input type="hidden" id="bar" value="YourHiddenValue" />
<button ng-click="processForm()"> SUBMIT </button>
</form>
```

and then in the JavaScript controller:

```
$scope.formData.bar = "";
try {$scope.formData.bar = document.getElementById("bar").value;} 
catch(e) {alert(e.message);}
alert("foo="+$scope.formData.foo+ " bar="+$scope.formData.bar);
```

So you can have as many hidden fields as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-binding="{{employee.data}}"`. It will work properly.